# getView returning null when fragment has been created from an activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a working tablet application which I am now trying to make work on phones too.
On a table there is two fragments on the screen a list fragment and a details fragment.
When on a phone the list fragment appears and creates a new activity when a list item is pressed.
This activity simply creates the fragment in the `onCreate()` method and commits it to the screen as follows.

```
// Place an DeallDetailsFragment as our content pane
DealDetailsFragment f = new DealDetailsFragment();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, f).commit();
getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

This is working as expected however from within this activity I need to tell the fragment what details to load and display. In my DealDetailsFragment class I have a `updateDeal()` method which updates the content as follows.

```
if (deal==null) { // could be null if user presses the loading deals list item before it loads
    return;
}
this.deal=deal;
if (dealTitle==null) { // get the view objects only once
    holder = new ViewHolder();  
    holder.dealHeat=(TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.dealDetails_heat_textView);
    holder.dealPrice=(TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.dealDetails_price_textView);
    holder.dealRetailer=(TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.dealDetails_retailer_textView);
    holder.dealTitle=(TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.dealDetails_title_textView);
    holder.dealDesc=(TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.dealDetails_desc_textView);
    holder.goToButton= (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.dealDetails_goToDeal);
    holder.dealImage=(ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.dealDetails_imageView);
    holder.postedBy=(TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.dealDetails_poster_textView);
    holder.datePosted=(TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.dealDetails_date_textView);
```

`getView()` is returning null when the application is ran on a phone where there is only a single fragment shown.

Any ideas? Unfortunately, there is not many fragment examples available online.

Comment: At what point in the Fragment lifecycle is the updateDeal method called?

Comment: When the fragment has been created and been loaded.

Comment: what method specifically? onCreate? onCreateView? onStart? onResume?

Comment: Currently in onCreate. I have also tried it in onStart.

Comment: See the following topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789519/fragment-getview-always-returning-null-for-fragments-created-by-a-fragmentstat

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Move your method call to be executed during `onCreateView`, and use the view you are inflating for reference instead of `getView()`. See the fragment lifecycle for more information: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating

and the documentation of `getView()` that explains why it returns null before `onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)` returns:

> **getView()**
>   Get the root view for the fragment's layout (the one returned by onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)), if provided.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView()

Comment: Perfect! Fortunately, it only too me 1 hour before finding this answer :).

Comment: finding view this way will provided a new view, but i want the reference of the same view??

Comment: Any idea why getView() can return null, even after onCreateView() has been called?

Comment: @AndrewOrobator make sure you're calling it during or after `onViewCreated()` in the lifecycle. Also make sure you're actually returning a non-null View during `onCreateView()`.

Comment: You saved my minute . :D

Answer (score 25):

Moving the method to `onCreateView()` did not help me.so... Create a global variable `mView`

```java
protected View mView;
```

and in onCreateView()

```java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  Log.d(TAG, "oncreateView");
  super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_secure_cloud_drive_folder, container, false);
  this.mView = view;
  return view;
}
```

and the replace all your `getView()` with `mView`

Comment: Also, set the mView = null inside onDetach() method to avoid memory leak

Comment: By using this, it becomes mView=null in certain scenario that causes crash in my app due to null point exception in viewbyId. App works fine in my mobile but I'm getting 4% crash because of this. Any idea on how to prevent this ?

Comment: What is the difference to just call `getView()`?

Answer (score 8):

You can fix that by putting your code inside the `onViewCreated()`-method, which you should override. Don't forget to call `super()` on it.

Comment: Somehow this is the best answer and underappreciated. I don't see why you should put your code in onCreateView if it has nothing to do with the inflation. You should just be a bit more serious, replace "doing X-things by" "put your code into the onViewCreated method".

Comment: There are situations where you need `getView()` outside of the lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 6):

You must check the Android Lifecycle to understand WHY is it null on 
onAttach(...) function.

The first function called when fragment is created is added is **onAttach()**,  but actually no view has been created. That's why null is returned when you try to access within this call.

Next function is **onCreate()**... but there is no view created yet!!!!

The third function called is **onCreateView()**, and it's here where you have to indicate which is the view attached to this fragment.... And it's only from this call where a view object exists and can be accessed.

Read and learn the full lifecycle [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Greetings

Answer (score 2):

Because onCreate() is called before onCreateView() , whether you inflate a view in onCreateView() or not, you'll get nothing through getView() in onCreate(), because in that time , **onCreate() has not been called yet** .

[image: Android Lifecycle]

Comment: I think you should add a source or something like this: http://i.imgur.com/6Jl56FA.jpg

Answer (score 1):

it becomes null basically because you call `getview()` before the view being inflated. Create a `View` object and fill using `inflater`and then find your UI element see code below

```
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_albumslist, container, false);
        TextView t= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtTest);
        t.setText(strtext);
        return view;
```