# Fragment getView() always returning null for Fragments created by a FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have been reading a lot about fragments. Have found other people having problems retrieving fragments view because null was always returned but no answer solved my problem. What I'm trying to do is create a image gallery. I have a Fragment that holds a image view. To show the fragments I use a android.support.v4.view.ViewPager. And to feed the `ViewPager` I use a `android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

The problem is that when everything is build and the images are shown I want to save the current shown image to disk. So I need to get the current fragment imageview but I can't because fragment.getView() always is null, the activity associated with the fragment is null too and I can't figure out why is it. Here some code to see if anyone could help here:

This is my Fragment:

```
public class ImageViewURLFragment extends Fragment 
{
    String _url;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // The last two arguments ensure LayoutParams are inflated
        // properly.
        View rootView = new ImageViewURL(getActivity(), _url);

        return rootView;
    }

    public void setImageURL(String imgURL)
    {
        _url=imgURL;
    }
}
```

And this my adapter:

```
public class ImageViewURLCustomAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter 
{
    List<String> _urls=new ArrayList<String>();

    public ImageViewURLCustomAdapter(FragmentManager fm) 
    {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) 
    {
        ImageViewURLFragment fragment = new ImageViewURLFragment();
        fragment.setImageURL(_urls.get(i));

        return fragment;
    }

    public String getItemUrl(int i)
    {
        return _urls.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return _urls.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
    }

    public void addImageURL(String url)
    {
        _urls.add(url);
    }
}
```

And this is the main activity, notice the comment with the get:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
{
    ImageViewURLCustomAdapter _iva=null;
    ViewPager _vp=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        _iva = new ImageViewURLCustomAdapter(
                        getSupportFragmentManager());
        _iva.addImageURL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/Saturn_(planet)_large.jpg");
        _iva.addImageURL("http://planetthreesixty.com/sites/default/files/planet.jpg");

        _vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        _vp.setAdapter(_iva);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        if(item.getItemId()==R.id.saveToSD)
        {
            int index= _vp.getCurrentItem();
            Fragment fragment=_iva.getItem(index);

            //THis is where I need to get fragment view, but always returns null
                    View view= fragment.getView();
            ImageView iv=(ImageView)view.findViewWithTag("imageView");
            Bitmap bmp=iv.getDrawingCache();


        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Sorry for the long sources, I have cleaned everything I could, but I wanted to present all playing parts. Could anybody guess what is hapenning?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> So I need to get the current fragment imageview but I can't because
>   fragment.getView() always is null, the activity associated with the
>   fragment is null too and I can't figure out why is it.

That is happening because you're expecting `_iva.getItem(index);` to return the `Fragment` that the `ViewPager` uses for the page corresponding to the specified index. That will not happen as the `ViewPager` has already called the `getItem` method to get the fragments it needs and after your call the `getItem` method you get a new `ImageViewURLFragment` instance. This new instance isn't tied to the `Activity`(`getActivity()` returns `null`) and its view wasn't created.

As you use a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` try the code below to get the currently visible `Fragment`:

```
if (item.getItemId()==R.id.saveToSD) {
     int index = _vp.getCurrentItem();
     Fragment fragment = _vp.getAdapter().instantiateItem(_vp, index);
     //...
```

Comment: After searching for some more info, I would like to ask how did you get this information about instantiateItem.I mean I have read that this adapter can reuse fragments instead of creating a new one everytime, but where did you find information that we could call instantiateItem directly and that this would return a previous instance of the fragment and not a new one? And on the other hand how would you do this (get current item) for a PageView?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Notbad If you look at the source code for the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` you'll see that the `instantiateItem` method will either return a cached fragment or a new fragment. In the case when you're looking for the current fragment it will be the cached version. *And on the other hand how would you do this (get current item) for a PageView?* - I don't understand what you're asking. To get the current fragment from a FragmentStatePagerAdapter you would use my code from the answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think it is common practice to read android sources for this kind of things. Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for this one single line which I was looking for.

Fragment fragment = _vp.getAdapter().instantiateItem(_vp, index);

Comment: Works fine even beyond the scope of this question. :thumbsup:

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I have spend all day looking what was wrong, I didn/t know that getItem() returns new instance of a fragment (( Happy coding!