# How to convert this Activity to Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-view, findviewbyid

I'm developing my first app and i have the following code in my Activity that now i want to convert to Fragment (to use a tabbed activity);

```
public class StatTab1 extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stattab1);

        ListView lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        populateList();
        ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, list);
        lview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
...
```

I changed the code in this way:

```
public class StatTab1 extends Fragment {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ListView lview = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);
        populateList();
        ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), list);
        lview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {             
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stattab1, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
    ...
```

I get this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.NullPointerException.

Here is the LogCat:

```
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005): Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 18005
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.Stats}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005):    at com.example.myapp.StatTab1.onCreate(StatTab1.java:31)
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1678)
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:859)
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240)
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
10-03 21:10:30.915: E/AndroidRuntime(18005):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you paste the error message for us?

Comment: I edited my question adding the LogCat error messages. Thank you

Comment: Thanks.  Which line is StatTab1.java line 31?  It looks like that's where the error is.

Comment: ListView lview = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);

Answer (score 1):

I finally figure out the problem and i solved. This do the trick:

```
public class StatTab1 extends Fragment
{    
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {             
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stattab1, container, false);

        ListView lview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        populateList();
        ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), list);
        lview.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }
...
```

Comment: Cool, I was about to suggest moving it to onCreateView.  Here's a related post where that was the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488595/getview-returning-null-when-fragment-has-been-created-from-an-activity

Comment: I figure out the problem by myself :P Thank you anyway for your support ;)