# Android Get View In Fragment Returns Null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with two fragments, Fragment A and Fragment B. I want to show a view hidden in Fragment A when the user touches a button in fragment B. How can I do this? I have tried to get the whole layout of the activity and get the view but I get a null pointer exception.

My activity layout is as shown below
[image]
This is the line I am using. It throws a null pointer exception.

```
shadowLine = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.shadowLine);
shadowLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: either you can use Interface for callback or user Broadcast for update your view.

Comment: please look at here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700798/basic-communication-between-two-fragments

Comment: can  you show me the full code?

Comment: Check out solution in below link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9505298/7989770

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way, not the safest: 
You can access hosting activity in fragment B by

```
HostActivity activity =(HostActivity) getActivity();
activity.callOtherFragment();
```

In that activity, you can access fragment A, by

```
public void callOtherFragment() {
    YourFragment A = (YourFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentA);
    A.showSomeStuff();
}
```

then implement your method in fragment A:

```
public void showSomeStuff() {
  shadowLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```