# Android kotlin - Unresolved reference for setImageBitmap in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin

I just try to set a Bitmap inside an ImageView in fragment:

```
imageLeft.setImageBitmap(duelbildBitmap)
```

and get `Unresolved reference` for `setImageBitmap`

Why? It works in activity

Thanks in advance

Comment: Type of variable is ImageView?  `var imageView : ImageView`

Comment: yes. I tried the exacly same id's etc in activity

Comment: Are you referring to layout id by writing imageLeft?

Comment: Let me see, how you have included ImageView in layout, and what is import line you have in your kotlin class. Or just show full code related to this issue.

Comment: It's kotlin, no probs doing it that way. If anything would be wrong with the variable then setImageBitmap wouldn't be Unresolved reference, the problem lies in the fact that it's inside fragment and I need workaround

Comment: In fragment, ids are not referred like activity. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708920/6891563

Comment: Ok it's this way: import com.amoflirt.amoflirt.R.id.imageLeft correct so? What are you suggesting?

Comment: `R.id.imageLeft` returns integer id, not ImageView object bro. So int value does not have `setImageBitmap` method.

Comment: Either do findViewById() or do it like https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708920/6891563

Comment: show how you declared your `imageView`

Comment: I tried val picleft = findViewById(R.id.imageLeft) now and get unresolved reference for findViewById

Comment: See answer bro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not just use `R.id.imageView`, because that is **`integer`** id not the `ImageView` object. So it can not find `setImageBitmap()` method on `Integer`.

You have two ways

#### 1: by using `findViewById()`

```
class GalleryFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var viewOfLayout: View
    private lateinit var imageView: ImageView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        viewOfLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false)
        return viewOfLayout
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap) // set bitmap anywhere
    }
}
```

#### 2: by using `kotlinx.android.synthetic`

```
class GalleryFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var viewOfLayout: View
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        viewOfLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false)
        viewOfLayout.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap) // set bitmap anywhere
        return viewOfLayout
    }
}
```

If imageView is not imported automatically in this case, then import manually.

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment.view.*
```

In second method you have to apply plugin `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` if not applied at the end of app level `build.gradle` file.

Comment: No it was example, make imageview object at class level and use it anywhere in your class.

Comment: In second method, you can use `viewOfLayout.imageView.setImageBitmap()` anywhere in your class.

Comment: In first method you can use `imageView.setImageBitmap` anywhere.

Comment: This is the "JAVA way" to do it and I learned JAVA only like 1 hour before I puked and never touched it again

Comment: I suggest learn data binding of android, in that you can just use `binding.imageView`. And there are many other benefits of binding, like live reload of UI when data changed.

Comment: Ok I will take a look at that. Thanks again